# Dropdown menu links show on Focus

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to get the dropdown links to show (on focus) on when tabbing with the keyboard. Tried a couple different styles, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
   background: #005bbb;
   font: 14px Sofia,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1;}

.nav-global a {text-decoration: none}

.nav-global ul li {
    color: #005bbb;
    float: left; 
 display: inline; 
 position: relative; 
 margin: 0;
 width: 235px}
 
.nav-global ul li:hover {
 background-color: #003e51;}

 
/* style the first level slightly different */

.nav-global > ul > li {
 margin: 0;
 width: auto;
 background: #fff;
 color: #005bbb}

.nav-global ul li a {
 color: #005bbb;
 padding: 12px 16px 14px 16px;
 display: block; 
 font: 15px Sofia Bold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}
 
.nav-global ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff}
 
.nav-global > ul > li > a {}

.nav-global li:hover > a  {color: #fff} 
 
  
/* ----------------------------------------------- secondary nav ----------------------------------------------- */




.nav-global ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 max-height: 0; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 margin: 0; 
 opacity: 0;}

.nav-global ul li:hover > ul {
 max-height: 1000px; 
 overflow: visible; 
 opacity: 1;}
 
.nav-global ul li ul li {
 background-color: #003e51;}
 
.nav-global ul li ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 font: 13px Sofia, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-indent: 15px;}


.nav-global ul li ul li a:hover {
 background: #002935;}

.nav-global ul li ul li:first-child {
 padding-top: 10px}

.nav-global ul li ul li:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 10px}
.
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
<nav class="nav-global">

    <ul>
     <li><a href="/findmaterials" class="find">Find Materials</a>
     
      <ul>
      <li><a href="/findmaterials/everything">Everything</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://catalog.lib.buffalo.edu/">Catalog</a></li>
   <li><a href="/findmaterials/databases">Databases</a></li>
   <li><a href="/findmaterials/ebooks">E-Books</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://ll3md4hy6n.search.serialssolutions.com">E-Journals</a></li>
   <li><a href="/reserve">Course Reserve</a></li>
   <li><a href="/off-campus">Off Campus Access</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
          </ul>
   
   
   
   </nav>
    </div>
 =
```

I tried using the code like this for "on focus", but not working:

```
.nav-global ul li:focus > ul {
max-height: 1000px; 
overflow: visible; 
opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Simply linking to your website is not sufficient.

Comment: It's not my website. Just the navigation by itself. Nothing else.

Comment: Understood, but you should still be able to produce a minimal example and provide code so others can help you.

Comment: I put it into a JSFiddle.

Comment: First of all, `li` is not a focus-able element on its own - you need to give it a tabindex, before it can receive focus. Secondly, `:focus` is no good to show a sub-navigation - because the `li` will _loose_ focus, as soon as the user tabs on to the first link inside the sub-navigation. What you actually want, is `:focus-within` - but be aware of browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within Long story short, if you want decent browser support now - you want a JavaScript solution.

Comment: I need to show it for accessibility purposes. The links in the dropdown need to be accessible when someone tabs to them with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add `tabindex="0"` to `nav-global` and the `:focus` selector will work. In the code snippet below I apply this change and also add all sub-menu links to the `tabindex` order. Refer to [this technique for WCAG 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H4.html).

Please note that once you open the menu with the tab key, your next tab will close the menu since `nav-global` looses focus, as indicated in a comment to your question. If the mouse is hovering over the menu, it will remain open, and you can type TAB to see how each link in the `tabindex` receives focus.

I would suggest controlling menu visibility with javascript so you don't rely on css to maintain its state. Js can give you more control over the user experience. For instance, adding a keyhandler to close the menu when ESC is typed.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background: #005bbb;
  font: 14px Sofia, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}

.nav-global a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.nav-global ul li {
  color: #005bbb;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 235px
}

.nav-global ul li:hover {
  background-color: #003e51;
}


/* style the first level slightly different */

.nav-global>ul>li {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background: #fff;
  color: #005bbb
}

.nav-global ul li a {
  color: #005bbb;
  padding: 12px 16px 14px 16px;
  display: block;
  font: 15px Sofia Bold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.nav-global ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.nav-global>ul>li>a {}

.nav-global li:hover>a {
  color: #fff
}


/* ----------------------------------------------- secondary nav ----------------------------------------------- */

.nav-global:focus>ul>li>ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-global>ul>li:focus>ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-global:focus>ul>li {
  background-color: #003e51;
}

.nav-global:focus>ul>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.nav-global ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-global ul li:hover>ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-global ul li ul li {
  background-color: #003e51;
}

.nav-global ul li ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 13px Sofia, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 15px;
}

.nav-global ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #002935;
}

.nav-global ul li ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px
}

.nav-global ul li ul li:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px
}

.
```

```html
<div class="nav-main">
  <nav class="nav-global" tabindex="0">

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/findmaterials" class="find" tabindex="-1">Find Materials</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="/findmaterials/everything" tabindex="0">Everything</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://catalog.lib.buffalo.edu/" tabindex="0">Catalog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/findmaterials/databases" tabindex="0">Databases</a></li>
          <li><a href="/findmaterials/ebooks" tabindex="0">E-Books</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://ll3md4hy6n.search.serialssolutions.com" tabindex="0">E-Journals</a></li>
          <li><a href="/reserve" tabindex="0">Course Reserve</a></li>
          <li><a href="/off-campus" tabindex="0">Off Campus Access</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>



  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is what I am trying to get the navigation to do: https://youtu.be/hDl-3JA8mJ0

I need to be able to tab to all the links in the dropdown. Seems as though this is using javascript. Thanks for the help. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I believe you need a js solution. Structure the menu as you have and include your menu items in the tabindex order with `tabindex="0"`. You can use `onmouseover` and `onfocus` to open the menu. Keep the menu open unless a specific action is taken, e.g. when menu item is selected, when ESC is typed, when the user clicks outside of the menu. Since tabindex items are in sequential order in the DOM, the menu should work as in your video. To create a menu with js, please refer to [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp)